# Scala specify params

Tags: scala

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // attach to IRC if irc param is specified
    if(args.contains("--irc")){
        bot = new PircBotX(new Configuration.Builder()
            .setName("GameNotifier")
            .setNickservPassword(args(args.indexOf("--irc") + 1))
            .setServerHostname("IRCSERVER")
            .setServerPort(6667)
            .addListener(new GameIRCListener)
            .buildConfiguration())
        new Thread(new Runnable { def run() { bot.startBot() }}).start()
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        bot.sendRaw().rawLine("JOIN " + ircChannel + " " + args(args.indexOf("--irc") + 2) + "\n")
    } else run = true
```

How do I go about specifying the irc param and getting --irc in the arg?

EDIT:

I'm compiling/packaging to a .jar using SBT. Whenever I run without --irc I have no issues but when ran with --irc it throws the following

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.trade.TraderMain$.main(TraderMain.scala:35)
        at org.trade.TraderMain.main(TraderMain.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 24, 2015 3:07:23 AM
```

Comment: "at org.trade.TraderMain$.main(TraderMain.scala:35)" Which is line 35?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you provide smth next to "--irc?", because this line shows that you trying to get the next argument, if it doesn't exist, it throw indexOutOfBoundException.

```
.setNickservPassword(args(args.indexOf("--irc") + 1))
```